# How do I host/deploy a Node.js app/server on a web hotel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, deployment, hosting

I can’t seem to find a good answer to this, no matter where I look. All I see are code examples of a basic Node.js application, to get things started.

But after having created all prerequisite code and files like this, how am I supposed to make it work on a web server? How do I upload it and make it run on my domain at my web hotel?

Do I upload the files and run them via an SSH command, or how do I make Node.js run in the first place? I already have a domain and a web hotel account, so services like Heroku are probably out of the question (unless I’ve missed something).

Thank you!

Comment: do you have sudo privileges on the server?

Comment: @VassilisPallas Whilst connected via SSH? I’m not sure, as this could be vulnerable to the web hotel I guess, but let me check.

Comment: @VassilisPallas `sudo` isn’t installed at /usr/bin/, so I guess not. Maybe I have `root` privileges, but still I’d doubt that.